# using the access_token from gapi with older google data js library

Tags: javascript, gdata, google-contacts-api, google-api-js-client

I have existing code that uses the new gapi javascript library. From there, I can get the access token with gapi.auth.getToken() . Is it possible to use that access token when making calls with the older Google Data JS library?

Specifically, I need to access the Google contacts list of the user using the older Google Data JS library (the new gapi library doesn't support the Contacts API).